# Questions about intersection of algebraic subgroups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups, affine-schemes, group-schemes

I have a question related to Proposition 1.49 of the book Algebraic Group of Milne. Here is the excerpt:

[image]

My question is the last line. I don't really understand the reasoning in that line. From what I understand, $H_j$ is a closed subscheme of $G$, which is affine, so if $G = Spec(R)$, then $H_j \subset G$, and $I(H_j) = \bigcap_{p \in H_j}p$, which is an ideal of $R$. So each $f \in I(H_j)$ is an element of $R$, which can be considered as a function on $Spec(R) = G$. How does this function $f$ act on some $g \in G(R) = Hom(SpecR, G)$? And why is that line true eventually?

If you don't understand any notion/symbol from the excerpt, please tell me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This notation is explained in 3.2 of the book. Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group.

For a $k$-algebra $R$, $G(R)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-algebra}}(\mathcal{O}{}(G),R)\simeq
\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-algebra}}(\mathcal{O}{}(G)_{R},R)$.

An $f\in\mathcal{O}(G)$ defines an evaluation map
$f_{R}\colon G(R)\rightarrow R,\quad g\mapsto g(f)=f_{R}(g),$
which is natural in $R$.

If $H$ is the subgroup of an affine group scheme $G$ corresponding to an ideal $I$, then $H(R)=Hom(\mathcal{O}/I,R)
=\{g\in G(R)=Hom(\mathcal{O},R)|g(f)=0\text{ all }f\in I\}$

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. But can you please explain further why the equality of that last line is true?

Comment: For me, at least when $H_j = G$, then the equation reads: $G(R) = \{g \in G(R) | 
 g(f) = 0 \forall f \in N(A)\}$. Here $N(A)$ is the nilradical of $A$, and $G = Spec(A)$. It is not true in general, because $R$ is not reduced.